# white gap space with a svg

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image]

over the first text and the svg from the above i have a white gap space how can i remove that white space  here is the code

```css
h1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div className="wave-wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path
          fill="black"
          fill-opacity="1"
          d="M0,128L288,96L576,0L864,256L1152,64L1440,160L1440,320L1152,320L864,320L576,320L288,320L0,320Z"
        ></path>
      </svg>
  <h1>testing</h1>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path
          fill="black"
          fill-opacity="1"
          d="M0,128L48,122.7C96,117,192,107,288,85.3C384,64,480,32,576,58.7C672,85,768,171,864,181.3C960,192,1056,128,1152,112C1248,96,1344,128,1392,144L1440,160L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"
        ></path>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you have no margins set on the `h1` element.

Just add `display: block;` to the `svg` elements. It should do the trick.

Comment: thanks that worked but can you explain why?

Comment: You can look at linked questions. Many people explained it and they have done it definitely better than I would do it.